# GCM error sending messages at server

Tags: tomcat, push-notification, api-key, google-cloud-messaging

I get following error when trying to send a message from GCM demo server. The code is same as supplied at developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html and it's run on Tomcat. The device gets registered on the server and shows "1 device(s) registered!". But i get following error when "send message" button is pressed.
(I have placed the api key i received from https://code.google.com/apis/console/ in "api.key" file.)

Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - HTTP Status Code: 401

**type** Exception report

**message** HTTP Status Code: 401

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.35

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900855/http-response-code-401-in-google-gcm

Comment: Thanx @Sangharsh but i tried all solutions provided in that post as well. But none helped me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just copy gcm-demo.war into apache webapps folder and then run.Definitely it will run.